# JAXB: Write general purpose XmlAdapter that handles multiple implementations of an interface: retrieve construction parameter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have an interface `Animal` and a number of implementations (`Cat`, `Dog` and `Sheep`) in a jar `animals-core` that does not depend on JAXB. Then I have a jar `animals-jaxb` that provides JAXB bindings for these classes.

What I 'd like to write is this:

```
public class AnimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Animal> {

    @Override
    public Animal unmarshal(String content) {
        switch (fieldClass) {
            case Cat.class: return new Cat(content);
            case Dog.class: return new Dog(content);
            case Sheep.class: return new Sheep(content);
            default: throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "propertyClass (" + propertyClass + ") not supported");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Animal a) {
        return a.toContent();
    }

}
```

This would make it very easy for the users of my animals framework to configure:

```
public class Person {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnimalAdapter.class)
    private Cat cat; // fieldClass is Cat.class
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnimalAdapter.class)
    private Dog dog; // fieldClass is Dog.class
}
```

**The problem with the code above is the lack of `fieldClass`: for an `XmlAdapter` instance, I can't find a way to retrieve to type of field that it's bound to. Is this possible?**

Comment: Hi, did you find any thing, because i am also looking for the solution, please share if you have found solution,

Comment: No, JAXB doesn't support it. XStream does...